# C# Web Service XmlSerializer issue

Tags: c#, web-services, xml-serialization

I have a C# Web Service that is serializing my simple class:

```
    [Serializable]
    [XmlInclude(typeof(Bitmap))]
    [XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    public class Class1 
    {
        private static Bitmap _myImage = new Bitmap(@"C:\WebApplication1\ClassLibrary1\Untitled.png");


        public Bitmap MyImage
        {
            get { return _myImage; }

            set
            {
                _myImage = value;
            }
        }
    }
```

Here's the asmx.cs code that does the serialization:

```
[WebMethod]
public string HelloWorld()
{
    var c = new Class1();
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Class1));

    return XMLSerializer(c);
}

public string XMLSerializer(object pObject)
{
    try
    {
        XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(pObject.GetType());
        using (StringWriter stream = new StringWriter())
        {
            xs.Serialize(stream, pObject);
            stream.Flush();
            return stream.ToString();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return ex.ToString();
    }

}
```

Looks prety straight forward.  However, the XML generated by the XmlSerializer is producing and error when I try to DeSerialize it.

```
{"There is an error in XML document (5, 5)."}
{"Parameter is not valid."}
```

When I try to load the generated XML into IE I get this error.

```
Switch from current encoding to specified encoding not supported. Error processing resource 'file:///C:/Users/mhall15/Deskt...

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
```

Here's the generated XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<Class1 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <MyImage xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
    <Palette />
  </MyImage>
</Class1>
```

Any ideas what's going on?

Comment: Can you post deserialization code? Maybe something wrong with it?

Comment: Also, it is looks like despite bitmap get serialised it doesn't have actual image in it. I would write Bitmap to byte[] and than serialised it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

During the serialization, replace "encoding="utf-16" with "encoding="utf-8"" and that will cut it.  The source of the problem - I'm not sure, but I've ran into it numerous times, and that's how I dealt with it.

That's how to deal with the IE issue.

The deserialization should be amongst these lines.  I'm posting the kind of arbitrary code I normally use:

```
public static object DeserializeFromXML<T>(string _input)
    {
        object _temp = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
        Type expected_type = _temp.GetType();
        _temp = null;
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(expected_type);
        StringReader stringWriter = new StringReader(_input);
        object _copy = serializer.Deserialize(stringWriter);
        return _copy;
    }
```

In the above example, I'm using templating for reusability sake.  You should be able to call the method by saying **DeserializeFromXML < Class1 >(_xml_input)** where xml input is the string.  That will force the compiler to use the definition of the given class to deserialize the XML input.  That way you wouldn't even have to change the encoding in the serialization.  If it's also a case where you may or may not know the data type to deserialize with, you can use a strategy design pattern where you register the root type of the XML with it's associated generic type.  Later on you can reference that registry and arbitrarily deserialize any XML input as long as the root type is registered.  It's a trick i normally use as well.  If more is needed on this, let me know, and I'll explain in detail.

In addition,if you are running IE 9, the new update to IE 9 makes it difficult to view XML.  Press F12 - go to developer tools and change your browser mode to run as IE 8 instead of IE 9.

Comment: Are you commenting on the IE issue?

Comment: @Neel...Cool, when you say "during the serialization" do you mean do a String.Replace( "encoding="utf-16",  "encoding="utf-8")

Comment: @Neel that fixed the IE issue, but the XML Error is still happening on Deserialization.

Comment: @MikeTWebb Thus my comment..... That is not really a solution. You just state that the file is another encoding than it is

Comment: Well he did say "When I try to load the generated XML into IE I get this error." So that's all I addressed. @MikeTWebb Yes, a basic string replace will do.  Normally my responses are a lot more detailed, but since the issue is just "loading into IE", that's pretty much all I figured you needed to know. Forgive me if it was too short.  The deserialization issue... I will put in the answer - I don't think I have enough space.

Comment: In addition, as @SergeyOsypchuk said in a previous comment, try storying the Bitmap bytes as a byte[] array.  I don't think you can serialize a Bitmap object.

Comment: @Neel....no worries.  It's all good.  And the byte[] array did the trick.  If you want to add that to you answer I'll accept it.  Sound good?

Comment: Nah, it's okay, at the end of the day, Silverlight is just a game I like to play.  Thanks for the brain teaser.